# C++ show an icon оverlay over all empty folders

Tags: c++, windows, shell, overlay, windows-shell

I am searching for the C++ solution to show icon overlay over the folder. but I have noticed that it's really bad idea to code overlays in .NET\Java  +Shell because interpreter is called all the time you are using explorer.

So I have example how to do add icon over files which contains some text: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/overlayicon.aspx

And I need to mark with my icon all empty folders. How can i do that?

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Question is about how to know whether a folder has anything. Because i dont know anything about c++. And can i call handler function from c# for some specified folder?  Any examples?

Comment: Why do you want to call the shell icon handler? The shell is expected to do that. You simply provide the functionality to the shell and it consumes the handler shell extension whenever it needs to paint shell objects.

Comment: I want to call this handler because i need to mark only specific folders. So when customer will configure\change list of folders i need to draw special icons over folders when they empty.

Comment: You don't understand shell extensions. The shell calls the handler. It asks for the overlay icon. Your code checks whether or not the item in question is an empty folder. If so then you return your icon. If not then you tell the shell not to draw an overlay.

Comment: Thats not good. Because i need also mark folder with icon if folder contains only empty folders... So that means complex check when any folder  is opened!?

Comment: @Evgeny You might get away with that because it's very quick to check and as soon as you find anything in any folder that it not a folder then you can stop checking. The worst case is when you have a deep structure with huge numbers of empty folders but my guess is that is rare. You would have to watch out for network volumes or non-mounted items. But for local storage it might just work. That said, why not stick at just one level of recursion for the overlay and add a context menu option to check recursively? That sounds like a good compromise.

Comment: Actually customer have huge amout of empty folders because some strange api) So thats why he need this overlay icons. And in example how can i get only folders in GetOverlayInfo method?

Comment: "How can i get only folders in GetOverlayInfo method?" I don't understand what you mean. Are you sure you want to do this with an overlay icon? What is the client going to do with the knowledge that a folder is empty, or only contains folders that are empty?

Comment: He will not open them! He want to see only folders with data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a COM object that implements IShellIconOverlayIdentifier like that codeproject article.

Your IsMemberOf method would look something like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP YourClassThatImplementsIShellIconOverlayIdentifier::IsMemberOf(PCWSTR pwszPath,DWORD Attr)
{
    if (!(Attr&FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) return S_FALSE; // Not a folder

    UINT count = 0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW wfd;
    LPWSTR bufSpec = (LPWSTR) LocalAlloc(LPTR,(lstrlenW(pwszPath)+2+1)*sizeof(WCHAR));
    if (bufSpec)
    {
        lstrcpyW(bufSpec,pwszPath);
        PathAddBackslashW(bufSpec);
        lstrcatW(bufSpec,L"*");
        HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(bufSpec,&wfd);
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE!=hFind) do
        {
            ++count;
        } while( count<= 2 && FindNextFileW(hFind,&wfd) );
        FindClose(hFind);
        LocalFree(bufSpec);
    }

    return count==2 ? S_OK : S_FALSE;
}
```

(A empty folder contains two special entries, "." and "..")

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistakes. I'm not having a good day today!